# PHP / MySQL: Undefined index after user update a data

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I develop a system that required an update function. The flow of the system will be like this:

1) list of data row in dashboard.php

2) User can select one of the data to view the details. It will redirect to view_task.php

3) At view_task.php, user can update the task name and click 'save' button to save.

The problem is. After I click button save, It will show the error 'undefined index: report id at line 7' and "undefined variable: task_name at line 55"

below is my current code:

view_task.php

```
<?php

  require_once "../../../../config/configPDO.php";
  require_once "../../../../config/check.php";

  $report_id = $_GET['report_id']; //line 7

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ot_report WHERE report_id = :report_id";
  $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));
  while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

      $report_id = $row["report_id"];
      $task_name = $row["task_name"];
  }

?>

<form action="update_task_name.php" method="POST">
  <td><b>Task Name</b></td>
  <td colspan = '2'><input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name" value="<?php echo $task_name; ?>"/></td> //line 55
  <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $report_id ?>"> 
  <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value = "Save" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')"></td>
</form>
```

update_task_name.php

```
<?php

    require_once '../../../../config/configPDO.php';

    $update = "UPDATE ot_report SET task_name = :task_name WHERE report_id = :report_id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($update);
    $stmt->bindParam(':task_name', $_POST['task_name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':report_id', $_POST['report_id']);
    $stmt->execute();

    class Result {}
    $response = new Result();
    $response->result = 'OK';
    $response->message = 'Update successful';
    header("Location: view_task.php");

?>
```

Although get the error at view_task.php, but the data successfully save!

Can anyone know what is the error?

Comment: seems like your query is probably not giving you value in $report_id and $task_name

Comment: @bilalmalik can you now how to solve it?

Comment: print_r($_POST) in update_task_name.php, and let us know if you are getting the values

Comment: @bilalmalik at which line?

Comment: Wen you are calling `header("Location: view_task.php");`, you didn't pass the 'report_id' as the parameter

Comment: @ViperLiu can you solve the problem by edit my code above?

Comment: before $update = "UPDATE ot_report SET task_name = :task_name WHERE report_id = :report_id";, can you do print_r

Comment: just pass report_id as the parameter to view_task.php. It should be like this `header("view_task.php?report_id=".$_POST['report_id'])`

Comment: What are you talking @ViperLiu, he is doing it with POST method as stated in form tag, thats not an issue

Comment: the error are happen in the view_task.php, and update_task_name.php excuted without error

Comment: So something must be wrong after the redirection

Comment: @ViperLiu, successful update and stay on the same page. but I need to click back button twice to go to the dashboard.php

Comment: So the update_task_name.php work without any errors, right?

Comment: @Yes, but I must click back button twice to go to the previous page. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that:

> Although get the error at view_task.php, but the data successfully save!

Base on that, I can assume that you entered the view_task.php from the dashboard.php without any error

And error only happen after you click SAVE button.

So, `task_name` and `report_id` must be sent to the update_task_name.php successfully

But when you try to redirect back to task_view.php with:

```
header("Location: view_task.php");
```

you didn't bring `report_id` to view_task.php, and caused the error you mentioned in your question

SO, here is my answer, in your update_task_name.php

replace this:

```
header("Location: view_task.php");
```

with this:

```
header("view_task.php?report_id=".$_POST['report_id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is this...

just access your page with a valid report_id

```
localhost/project_name/view_task/1
```

You're probably not proving the id in the url, hence view_task query itself is not working because it is not getting the id from the URL for GET method.

Comment: Now you know where is the problem

Comment: I think this is not the proper answer. I still didn't understand

Comment: problem ain't here - header("view_task.php?report_id=".$_POST['report_id']);, he is just not proving id in the URL

Comment: @PeterSondak then are you passing the report_id from dashboard to view_task using POST method? , if yes then on line 7 you'll need to do $_POST['report_id'] insetead of $_GET

Comment: @bilalmalik echo "<a class='btn-view btn-primary btn-sm' href='view_task/view_task.php?report_id=". $row['report_id'] ."' data-toggle='tooltip'>View</a>";

Comment: @bilalmalik this is how i passed

Comment: @PeterSondak that is correct, then inspect and see if you're getting value in $row['report_id']

Answer (score 0):

This all is overly complex, because it is quite simple:

```
/* initialize variables before already */
$report_id = -1;
$task_name = '';

/* check if the $_GET has a numerical report_id */
if(isset($_GET['report_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['report_id'])) {

    /* then dare to access $_GET['report_id'] */
    $report_id = $_GET['report_id']; //line 7

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ot_report WHERE report_id = :report_id";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $task_name = $row["task_name"];
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Extended the example, but the `while` loop seems strange for a single record.